# Adjusting alpha on overlaid rasters in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster

I'm trying to highlight a portion of a DEM using ggplot — essentially, just a colored, semi-transparent territorial subset.

As long as I do not add an 'alpha' argument to the overlaid subset, things look fine — I can plot my DEM as a geom_raster and add my second layer, either as another geom_raster or a geom_tile, on top. However, when I add an 'alpha' argument, the formerly transparent (NA) parts of my second layer lose their transparency, and wash out my DEM.

Does the 'alpha' argument convert the NAs to something else? How can I keep these areas transparent, while making the non-NA regions semi-transparent? Attached are two pictures for for those who don't want to run the code. What I want is for the circle to be at ~alpha = 0.5 (also for it to be colored), and for the space outside the circle to be fully transparent. I can't seem to get that result.

Thanks for your help!

```
# Create fake DEM
DEM.ex <- matrix(0, 100, 100)
DEM.ex[c(1:length(DEM.ex))] <- sin(c(1:length(DEM.ex))*0.5)
DEM.ex <- DEM.ex*t(DEM.ex)+1

# Create fake territory to highlight
territory.ex <- expand.grid(1:100, 1:100)
names(territory.ex)[c(1:2)] <- c("x", "y")
territory.ex$territory.z <- ifelse(sqrt((territory.ex$x-40)^2 + (territory.ex$y-40)^2) <= 30, 1, NA)
territory.ex$DEM.z <- DEM.ex[1:length(DEM.ex)]

# Plot
without_alpha <- ggplot(territory.ex) +
  geom_raster(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = DEM.z), na.rm = T) +
  geom_tile(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = territory.z), na.rm = T) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "black", high = "white", na.value = "transparent") +
  theme_light() +
  guides(fill = "none")

with_alpha <- ggplot(territory.ex) +
  geom_raster(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = DEM.z), na.rm = T) +
  geom_tile(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = territory.z), alpha = 0.5, na.rm = T) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "black", high = "white", na.value = "transparent") +
  theme_light() +
  guides(fill = "none")
```

[without_alpha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErSc6.png)
[with_alpha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6s6Vr.png)

Comment: Does switching the order of the `geom_tile()` and `geom_raster` change anything in the `with_alpha` graph? Sometimes the ordering can affect these things.

Comment: Hi. The code example is missing a definition of `g`. Please, edit code example so that it rauns. At the moment it triggers and error.
`Error in ifelse(sqrt((g$Var1 - 40)^2 + (g$Var2 - 40)^2) <= 30, 1, NA) : 
  object 'g' not found`

Comment: I fixed the 'g' definition. Apologies. The code works now.

Comment: Switching between geom_raster and geom_tile does not affect the issue. It's the same either way.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved.
Simply separate the data into different data frames or tibbles, omitting NA values for the overlay.

```
ggplot() +
geom_raster(data = territory.ex %>% dplyr::select(c(x, y, DEM.z)), 
            aes(x = x, y = y, fill = DEM.z), na.rm = T) +
geom_tile(data = territory.ex %>% subset(!is.na(territory.z)) %>% dplyr::select(c(x, y, territory.z)), 
          aes(x = x, y = y, fill = territory.z), na.rm = T, alpha = 0.5) +
scale_fill_gradient(low = "black", high = "white", na.value = "transparent") +
theme_light() +
guides(fill = "none")
```

[revised plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwRxt.png)